# How to make an action if there's no user input in x time

Tags: kotlin

As the title, is there any way to make an action if there's no user input in x time in Kotlin?

Im trying to achieve the following:

user input: hello

> hello

and if nothing happens the program prints:

> Are you there?

my code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    while (true){
        var echo = readLine()
        println(echo)

        println("Are you there?") // if x time passes and the user has not given input
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `repeat(x)` functionality if I understand the question correctly.

Moreover, can you please provide a code example of what you're trying to achieve, and why doesn't it work?

Comment: If you have code, can you edit your question to include it?

Comment: thanks for the help, just edited my post with my code and what Im trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This resource gives lots of information about how to measure elapsed time in Kotlin. You can use one of those and check how much time has passed each time through the loop. If the total time taken is greater than the desired time, print the statement.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-days-between-two-dates-in-android/